# How to perform FullText search on numeric column in MySQL to meet user requirements

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, query-performance

Having below table:

```
CREATE TABLE `event` (
      `eventId` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `eventTime` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ex: 1431201865000 (epoch in milliseconds)',
      `plateNumber` varchar(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ex: 5849',
      `plateCodeId` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'ex: 1 = A, 2 = D, 3 = Q, 4 = NY',
      PRIMARY KEY (`eventId`),
      KEY `eventTime` (`eventTime`),
      FULLTEXT INDEX `platenumberft` (`plateNumber`)
    ) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

**The User want to search plateNumber in form '%334%'**, knowing that's only supported by fulltext index, I wonder if its possible to avoid the usage of fulltext index since it create 6 tables and even I didn't find benchmarks highlight the impact of fulltext index on large table I am worried about the performance since the table above will hold over 1 billion records in which insertion rate is 150 records per second 24/7.

MySQL Docs recommends never to use string "varchar" data type to store numeric data, and since the platenumber always numeric, it should be created as:

```
`plateNumber` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

**Is it possible to query numeric field in search form '%334%' with speed equal to the fulltext index? and How?**

Use Case: the user received information that the plate number contain digits '334' in the middle, so the first and last digits are unknown.

Answer (score 4):

When searching for a numeric string in the *middle*, `FULLTEXT` is the *wrong* approach.  `LIKE` is the only approach, and it requires a full scan of the plates.  Live with it.

But... How often do you need to search for the *middle* of a string?  Not often.  If you have the *left* part of a string, `LIKE '234%'` works quite efficiently; it is a "range".  But then you need a regular `INDEX`, not `FULLTEXT`.

`FULLTEXT` is aimed at *words*, not substrings, not full strings.  Don't use it for licence plates.

Don't use `INT` for a plate number.  It is not a "number" on which you perform arithmetic; that is what the MySQL Doc is talking about.  The plate number is merely a string that often contains only digits, so use a `VARCHAR` with the minimal collation.  In the 'west', plates are numbers and *capital* letters.  So, `COLLATION ascii_bin` is optimal.  However, that means fold to upper case *both* the plate numbers *as they are stored*.  Also fold any query strings.  At the same time, remove any punctuation (dash, heart, star, etc) that is not actually important to the comparison.

I cannot address the collation specifics for Bangladesh, but I suspect that utf8_bin would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Consider ALTERing the table to add a new INT column for holding the digit(s) of a license number.

So for "*Use Case: the user received information that the plate number contain digits '334' in the middle, so the first and last digits are unknown.*" you could (quickly) search this column for `334`. Of course you're likely to have (potentially) many false positives--presumably you could then further filter the set to get the result(s) you want.

Another option would be to again ALTER the table (and CREATE two more tables) to create a many-to-many relationship where the 'many' side would contain the numbers (only) of a license. From your use case for example:

```
ID  Numbers
101 1
101 23
101 334
101 56
```

ETA: A third option would be to substitute one or more numeric values to each alpha via a lookup table. So for example this license (separators shown for clarity only):

```
1-ABC-334-FC-59
```

would be stored as this INT (separators shown for clarity only):

```
1-65-66-67-334-70-67-59
```

This has an obvious unintended consequence so if you do this, consider normalizing the alphas *and* the digits that are stored; plus doing the same to the search strings.

Answer (score 0):

1. Iraq,Iran,Afghanistan plate numbers: uses Indian digits https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plate
2. Bangladesh plates uses weird chars. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_Bangladesh

**From above, plate number shouldn't be integer, it must be varchar!**

Regarding MySql FullText indexing: **it is Big JOKE as it affect storage,insert speed by huge factor!**

I bench-marked on simple table with INT PK and varchar(10) column, On 3 Million Records:

```
table size without fulltext index:124 MB
1 million insert time: 14 seconds.


table size with fulltext index:436 MB
1 million insert time: 30 seconds.
```

**FullText index requires X3.5 larger storage! and insert time doubled!!**